# A command scope variable is left assigned after executing the command

Tags: bash, shell-script

Let's check the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh

func()
{
  echo "var: $var";
}

var="val" func

echo "after executing the command, var: $var"
```

Its output is:

```
var: val
after executing the command, var: val
```

The `var` variable is left set after executing the command.

Is it correct behavior? I thought that command scope variables are set just for a single command.

If I use `bash` (set `#!/bin/bash` in the first line) instead of `sh` then setting a variable for a command doesn't affect the rest of the script:

```
var: val
after executing the command, var:
```

In the *busybox* implementation `sh` and `bash` work equally: the variable is left assigned after executing the command.

To workaround the problem I use parentheses when executing such commands:

```
(var="val" func)
```

This way the `var` variable isn't touched in all shells.

Comment: "In bash, this is done only in bash mode, not in POSIX mode", and your shebang is `/bin/sh`.

Comment: I don't agree that my question is duplicate, but the accepted answer in the linked question fully satisfies me! Thank you!

Comment: @anton_rh Glad it worked for you.

Comment: it's a dupe because even though the variable name differs, it's the same problem with the same explanation/solution.